# Micro-applications in React using webpack and hooks

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have 3 React Applications(3 Micro-Frontends) built with webpack and module federation that comunicate with each other.
I can share components and a redux state with no problems. One of the three applications is the one that makes my API calls using some React hooks like useEffect, useState etc. The problem is that this micro-application never really makes the API calls as if the React hooks can't comunicate and send the response to the other micro applications.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?